# Проблемы c ListView

Tags: c++, winapi, listview

Написал простенькую ИС с ListView. Оказалось, что при добавлении данных из файла что-то идет не так, и все кроме первой колонки пишется в предыдущую строку. При подстановке заранее определенного значения в первый столбец - все работает. Кто-нибудь знает в чем проблема? Заранее спасибо.

main.cpp

```
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
#define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
#define UNICODE
#endif
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define WINVER 0x0501
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "Prog.h"
#include "Fac.h"

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HWND hListView, AddProg, AddCount, hwnd, hwnd_ed_name, hwnd_ed_count,      hwnd_ed_count1, hwnd_ed_fact, hwnd_ed_price, hwnd_ed_load, hwnd_ed_All;
Prog *ProgArr;
int Count = 0;
int selected;


TCHAR szClassName[ ] = _T("WindowsApp");

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPSTR lpszArgument,
                 int nCmdShow)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    MSG messages;
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;

    wincl.hInstance = hInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);


    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;

    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (0, szClassName, _T("LabFaculty"),    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, 544, 375, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    HWND hBtnAdd = CreateWindow ("BUTTON", "+/- шт", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                             2, 0, 100, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)10001, hInstance, NULL);
    HWND hBtnAddPro = CreateWindow ("BUTTON", "Доб. программу", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                             110, 0, 150, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)10002, hInstance, NULL);
    HWND hwnd_st_All = CreateWindow("static", "ST_U", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
                             300, 0, 90, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)(10003), hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowText(hwnd_st_All, "Общая цена");
    hwnd_ed_All = CreateWindow("edit", "",  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | ES_LEFT | WS_BORDER,
                             390, 0, 130, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)(10004), hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowText(hwnd_ed_All, "0");
    hListView=CreateWindowEx (0L, WC_LISTVIEW, "LW", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT |
                             LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT , 2, 35, 524, 300, hwnd, (HMENU)(10005), hInstance, NULL);
    ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(hListView,LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);

    LVCOLUMN column;
    memset(&column,0,sizeof(LVCOLUMN));
    column.mask=LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT;
    column.cx=370;
    column.pszText="Название";
    ListView_InsertColumn(hListView,0,&column);
    column.cx=70;
    column.pszText="Кол-во";
    ListView_InsertColumn(hListView,1,&column);
    column.cx=80;
    column.pszText="Цена за шт.";
    ListView_InsertColumn(hListView,2,&column);

    AddProg = CreateWindowEx (0, szClassName, _T("Доб. программу"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, 450, 250, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    HWND hwnd_st_name = CreateWindow("static", "ST_U", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
                        10, 10, 60, 20, AddProg, (HMENU)(20001), hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowText(hwnd_st_name, "Название");
    hwnd_ed_name = CreateWindow("edit", "",  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | ES_LEFT | WS_BORDER,
                        100, 10, 300, 20, AddProg, (HMENU)(20002), hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowText(hwnd_ed_name, "");
    HWND hwnd_st_cout = CreateWindow("static", "ST_U", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
                        10, 50, 60, 20, AddProg, (HMENU)(20003), hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowText(hwnd_st_cout, "Кол-во");
hwnd_ed_count = CreateWindow("edit", "",  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | ES_LEFT | WS_BORDER,
                        100, 50, 100, 20, AddProg, (HMENU)(20004), hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowText(hwnd_ed_count, "");
HWND hwnd_st_price = CreateWindow("static", "ST_U", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
                        10, 90, 80, 20, AddProg, (HMENU)(20005), hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowText(hwnd_st_price, "Цена за шт.");
hwnd_ed_price = CreateWindow("edit", "",  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | ES_LEFT | WS_BORDER,
                        100, 90, 100, 20, AddProg, (HMENU)(20006), hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowText(hwnd_ed_price, "");
HWND hBtnAddProg = CreateWindow ("BUTTON", "OK", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                             170, 170, 50, 30, AddProg, (HMENU)(20009), hInstance, NULL);

    AddCount = CreateWindowEx (0, szClassName, _T("+/- шт"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, 280, 150, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    HWND hwnd_st_count = CreateWindow("static", "ST_U", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
                        10, 10, 100, 20, AddCount, (HMENU)(30001), hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowText(hwnd_st_count, "+/- шт");
    hwnd_ed_count1 = CreateWindow("edit", "",  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | ES_LEFT | WS_BORDER,
                        120, 10, 100, 20, AddCount, (HMENU)(30002), hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowText(hwnd_ed_count1, "");
    HWND hBtnAddCount = CreateWindow ("BUTTON", "OK", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                             90, 60, 50, 30, AddCount, (HMENU)(30003), hInstance, NULL);



    ifstream Fin("base",ios_base::in);   //извлечение из файла
    string S;
    int i1,i2,i;
    TCHAR text_buf[3][100];
    const char *text_buf1;
    while (getline(Fin,S))
    {
        i1=0;i2=0;i=0;
        while (S[i2]!='\0')
        {
            if(S[i2]!='~')i2++;
            else
            {
                sprintf(text_buf[i],string(100,' ').c_str());
                sprintf(text_buf[i],S.substr(i1,i2).c_str());
                i++;
                S=S.substr(i2+1,S.length());
                i1=0;i2=0;
            }
        }
        strcpy(text_buf[2],S.substr(i1,i2).c_str());
        ProgArr[Count]=*new Prog(text_buf[0],atoi(text_buf[1]),strtod(text_buf[2],NULL));
        LVITEM item;
        memset(&item,0,sizeof(LVITEM));
        item.mask= LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_COLUMNS;
        item.iSubItem = 0;
        item.iItem = 0;
        item.pszText=text_buf[0];

        ListView_InsertItem(hListView,&item);
        ListView_SetItemText(hListView,0,1,text_buf[1]);
        ListView_SetItemText(hListView,0,2,text_buf[2]);
        Count++;
    }
    Fin.close();
    char text_buffT[100];
    sprintf(text_buffT,"%.2f",Fac::instance().TS());
    SetWindowText(hwnd_ed_All, text_buffT);


    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);
    ShowWindow (AddProg, SW_HIDE);
    ShowWindow (AddCount, SW_HIDE);



    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    return messages.wParam;
}



LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND Hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            if (LOWORD(wParam)==10002)
            {
                ShowWindow (AddProg, SW_SHOW);
            }
            else if (LOWORD(wParam)==10001)
            {
                selected = ListView_GetNextItem(hListView, -1, LVNI_SELECTED);
                ShowWindow (AddCount, SW_SHOW);
            }
            else if (LOWORD(wParam)==20009)
            {

                char text_buf[4][100];
                GetWindowText(hwnd_ed_name, text_buf[0], 100);
                SetWindowText(hwnd_ed_name, "");
                GetWindowText(hwnd_ed_count, text_buf[1], 100);
                SetWindowText(hwnd_ed_count, "");
                GetWindowText(hwnd_ed_price, text_buf[2], 100);
                SetWindowText(hwnd_ed_price, "");
                ProgArr[Count]=*new Prog(text_buf[0],atoi(text_buf[1]),atoi(text_buf[2]));
                ofstream Fout("base",ios_base::app);
                for(int i=0; i<2; i++) Fout << text_buf[i] <<"~";
                Fout << text_buf[2] << endl;
                Fout.close();
                LVITEM item;
                memset(&item,0,sizeof(LVITEM));
                item.mask=LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_COLUMNS;
                item.pszText=text_buf[0];
                item.iItem=0;
                ListView_InsertItem(hListView,&item);
                ListView_SetItemText(hListView,0,1,text_buf[1]);
                ListView_SetItemText(hListView,0,2,text_buf[2]);
                Count++;
                char text_buff[10];
                sprintf(text_buff,"%.2f",Fac::instance().TS());
                SetWindowText(hwnd_ed_All, text_buff);
                ShowWindow (AddProg, SW_HIDE);
            }
            else if (LOWORD(wParam)==30003)
            {
                char text_buf1[100];
                char text_buf2[100];
                char text_buf[100];
                GetWindowText(hwnd_ed_count1, text_buf1, 100);
                SetWindowText(hwnd_ed_count1, "");
                ListView_GetItemText(hListView,selected,1,text_buf2,100);
                sprintf(text_buf,"%.2f",atoi(text_buf1)+atoi(text_buf2));
                ListView_SetItemText(hListView,selected,1,text_buf);
                ProgArr[Count-selected].AddCount(atoi(text_buf1));
                ProgArr[selected].AddCount(atoi(text_buf1));
                sprintf(text_buf,"%.2f",Fac::instance().TS());
                cout << Fac::instance().TS();
                SetWindowText(hwnd_ed_All, text_buf);
                ShowWindow (AddCount, SW_HIDE);
            }
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:

            if (Hwnd != hwnd) ShowWindow (Hwnd, SW_HIDE);
            else DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc (Hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема в этом:

```
ListView_InsertItem(hListView,&item);
ListView_SetItemText(hListView,0,1,text_buf[1]);
ListView_SetItemText(hListView,0,2,text_buf[2]);
```

Вы сами сознательно пишите все в первый элемент списка (задается вторым параметром `ListView_SetItemText`. Исправление:

```
const int lineNo=ListView_InsertItem(hListView,&item);
ListView_SetItemText(hListView,lineNo,1,text_buf[1]);
ListView_SetItemText(hListView,lineNo,2,text_buf[2]);
```